# Merge rows based on values in 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have a table with travel details. Details are getting saved in distributed manner. I need to merge the rows based on Source and Destination. My Source is A and Final Destination is D, I need to merge all the 3 rows into 1 with sum of time and distance.

Table1:Trip details

| CarID | Source | Destination | Distance | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | B | C | 20 | 2 |
| 1 | C | D | 30 | 3 |

Table2: TravelPlan

| CarID | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | D |

Output Needed:
Table 3:

| CarID | Source | Destination | Distance | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | D | 60 | 6 |

I tried using Concatenate but not able to do based on conditions. Not sure how to combine rows of one table based on values of another.

Comment: SSMS is only client UI to SQL Server... it has nothing to do with the SQL itself.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show us.

Comment: Is there something like TripID in the first table?

Comment: No, I just have CarID which contains details about trips taken by each car.

Comment: Well, if one car is used several times for a particular trip how you are going to tell/map the data then?

Comment: There are two tables, one contain distributed trips (A->B, B->C, C->D) that a car took to cover the entire journey and another table contains the final journey (A->D). I need the result to be A->D with the sum of time and distance for final journey.

Comment: I guess the data model is not optimal. You should consider adding a date and some sort of trip ID. How does the data in destination and source look like?

Comment: you have to create a mapping table between that has the combination of all possible trips between A and D, that is A->B, B->C, C->D

Answer (score 2):

your Data

```
DECLARE @TripDetails TABLE (
   CarID       INT  NOT NULL 
  ,Source      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Destination VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Distance    INT  NOT NULL
  ,Time        INT  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @TripDetails
(CarID,Source,Destination,Distance,Time)
 VALUES 
(1,'A','B',10,1),
(1,'B','C',20,2),
(1,'C','D',30,3);


DECLARE @TravelPlan TABLE (
   CarID       INT  NOT NULL 
  ,Source      VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Destination VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @TravelPlan
(CarID,Source,Destination) VALUES 
(1,'A','D');
```

what you need are `Subquery` and `join` and `SUM`. your query

```
SELECT TP.carID,
       TP.Source,
       TP.Destination,
       TD.Distance,
       TD.Time
FROM   (select carID,
               Sum(Distance) Distance,
               Sum(Time)     Time
        FROM   @TripDetails
        GROUP BY carID) TD
       JOIN @TravelPlan TP
         ON TD.carID = TP.carID
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GsgchQAW)